# How to add Path Variables in RESTful Client

Tags: java, http

I make an HTTP GET request. My code is -

```
    // Set basic authentication
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = basicAuth(basicUser, basicPassword);
    SSLContext sslContext= getSSLContext();
    WebTarget webTarget = newRestClient(feature, sslContext, url);      
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    invocationBuilder = invocationBuilder.header(key, requestHeaders.get(key));
    final Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

Is there any way I can use the invocation builder to add path variables like NEW_PARAM in url/NEW_PARAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply it with an `url` of the form `url/{param}`, and then you can do:

```
webTarget = webTarget.resolveTemplate("param", "my-value");
```

In your example, you can just chain that method like so:

```
WebTarget webTarget = newRestClient(feature, sslContext, url)
                          .resolveTemplate("templateName", "my-value");
```